# Spring boot test - init of h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, testing, h2

I want to write integration test in spring boot using H2 database. I want tables to be created automaticly from @Entity classes.

My test class declaration

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DepartmentsTest {
...
```

and src/test/resources/application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Also I habe an entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bo_department")
public class BoDepartmentEntity
```

But when I run test, which uses BoDepartmentEntity I got an exception

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BO_DEPARTMENT" not found (this database is empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

H2 database is case sensitive by default. You could try to use uppercase in the annotation

```
@Table(name="BO_DEPARTMENT")
```

But this would be a code change for testing purpose only. A better solution is to set a Hibernate dialect to the one of the target database. Example for MySQL:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

In addition, if necessary, you can make your H2 case insensitive

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IGNORECASE=TRUE
```

Comment: But I see "(this database is empty)" in exception - that means, that database doesn't have any table.

Answer (score 0):

I got your question and found one fix which you can do.

you have configured below property like this:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Instead of "create" just give configuration like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-only
```

then it will work as per your requirement.